# For Loop- Multiple times C

Tags: c, for-loop

I am having trouble with C more than I thought I would. The goal of this segment of code is to read input from user and then based on that integer input the line "hello world" that number of times. I tried multiple different ways but every time my code would only execute 1 time.. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int  main()
{
   double x;

   printf("Enter a number from 1 to 5: ");
   scanf("%f", &x);
      for(int i =0; i <x; i++)
      {
          x= x-1;
          printf ("Hello World.\n");
      }
   }
```

Comment: Why do you increase `x` _and_ decrease `i`?

Comment: Why is the "number of times" a double instead of an integer?

Comment: why are you decrementing x?

Comment: read x as int (even double also not an issue), for(i=0;i<x;i++) printf("Hello world\n");  just enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't have to use `double`, which is a floating-point type. An integer is sufficient.

```
scanf("%d", &x);
```

Decrementing `x` in `for` loop is useless: `Hello world` will be printed from `(x - 1)  - 0  + 1 = x` times without this instruction.

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    printf("Hello world.\n");
}
```

Comment: this works. i guess the decrements in my for loop were causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing this line?

```
 x= x-1;
```

This causes the loop to iterate roughly half as much as it should. Each iteration, here's the comparison that happens

```
//user enters x=5
for(int i =0; i <x; i++)  // i == 0; x == 5; i < x is false
for(int i =0; i <x; i++)  // i == 1; x == 4; i < x is false
for(int i =0; i <x; i++)  // i == 2; x == 3; i < x is false
for(int i =0; i <x; i++)  // i == 2; x == 2; i < x is true, loop terminated!
```

Furthermore you are using doubles, ie

```
double x;
```

but expecting the user to enter integers.

While this doesn't lead to the specific bug you're seeing, you'll get better results if you change x to an int.

Comment: "`i == 0; x == 5; i < x is false`" While I understand what you're getting at, I think the distinction between true and false is an important one.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int  main()
{
   int x;
   int i;
   printf("Enter a number from 1 to 5: ");
   scanf("%d", &x);
      for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
      {
          printf ("Hello World.\n");
      }
}
```

the line `x = x - 1` (which by the way you could write it as `x--`) is pointless ,
and why did you choose `x` to be a `double` ?  you can't repeat "Hello world" 3.2 times